# Django_filters multiple arguments for non-model field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I need my endpoint to accept queries in the format:

`groupId=11111&groupId=22222` and resolve to a query:
`groupId=1111 OR groupId=2222`

I couldn't find anything in the documentation on how to do this, and made the following implementation (currently WIP, haven't written many tests):

```
    2 from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

   32 class CustomFilter(filters.UUIDFilter):
   33     def filter(self, qs, value):
   33         attr_name = next(k for k, v in self.parent.get_filters().items() if v.field_name == self.field_name)
   34         if attr_name  not in self.parent.data:
   35             return super().filter(qs, value)
   36
   37         q = Q()
   38         for val in self.parent.data.getlist(attr_name ):
   39             q |= Q(**{f"{self.field_name}__{self.lookup_expr}": val})
   40         return self.get_method(qs)(q)
```

Used like:

```
45     groupId = CustomFilter(field_name="group_id", help_text="Jobs associated with group")
```

> Is there a way to implement this using what is already in the framework?

Comment: Did you see this [issue on Github](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/137)? It has some options on how to solve it, but as far as I can see, there is no native implementation

Comment: I did find that one, but most solutions solve the problem from filters with comma 'groupdId=1,2,3' and also require pre-populated choices, which in my case would require a DB query to create.